# Suspeciously long pauses between Click and SendKeys actions in WDS in JMeter

Tags: time, jmeter, load, wds

I have an action which fills in a form with 2 fields and clicks submit button.

**Issue:** load time for this sampler grew up during several script runs from 2-3 sec initially (which was visually close to manual execution) to 14-16 sec with no visible reason (no changes in application or script).

**Investigation:** ~4-5sec pauses between click into a field and sendKeys actions for both 2 fields in script when manually fields are clickable with no visible delays after form appears.

**Log:**
[image]

**WDS code:**
[image]
[image]

**Q:** Is there any explanation of such strange behavior with ~5sec + ~5sec pauses in each field?

What should I do to fix this issue with too long and unexplainable pauses which provide unrelevant results?

Should I consider to switch to JSR223/groovy or it is not sampler type & code-related problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't tell the full story so I don't think it's possible to come up with the comprehensive answer so far only few generic recommendations:

1. Take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) at the moment when JMeter is "waiting" and doing nothing, it will allow you to detect what's going on there

   [image]
2. Monitor JVM parameters using [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) or equivalent, it might be the case the JVM is doing garbage collections to free up heap memory space, in this case you will have to [tune JMeter for maximum performance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/)
3. You're "finding" the element twice, the second line is absolutely unnecessary so instead of

   ```
   wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("some xpath")))
   var element = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("the same xpath"))
   ```

   you can do it only once like:

   ```
   var element = wait.until(pkg.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("some xpath")))
   ```
4. XPath is the most powerful but the [least performing locator strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/locating_elements/#tips-on-using-selectors), if it's possible - try to stick to element [ID attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp), if it is not possible - go for [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
5. Follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) like don't run your test in GUI mode, avoid storing response data, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitrii.

3,4,5 - will reconsider, thank you.
2 - no problem from this side.
1 - captured TreadDump. What should I pay attention to? Here are several strings with something "locked".

Comment: Should it be smth like that:

"TimerQueue" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002855c800 nid=0x5640 waiting on condition [0x000000002c4de000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006e1058f98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
...
   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006e20f6210> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)